# Finding 3x3 matrix from whose given characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a simple question but I was not able to solve it. Question is this:

**Find a 3x3 matrix whose charactestic polynomial is $\lambda\ ^3 - 2\lambda\ ^2 + \lambda\ + 5 $.**

Can you help me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Companion Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompanionMatrix.html)?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 no. I am not familiar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the $n \times n$ [Companion Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompanionMatrix.html) $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -a_0 \\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -a_1 \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & -a_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$ has the characteristic polynomial $a_0+a_1\lambda+\cdots+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\lambda^n$.

Now, simply apply this fact for $n = 3$ and $a_0 = 5$, $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = -2$, to get a $3 \times 3$ matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $5+\lambda-2\lambda^2+\lambda^3$.

Comment: So, 3x3 matrix like this:

1st row ==> [ 0 0 -5 ]

2nd row == > [1 0 -1]

3rd row == > [0 1 -2] 

Right?

Comment: Almost. Check the 3rd number on the 3rd row again. But the other 8 entries are correct.

Comment: last row is [0 1 2].  a little bit carelessness! :)) Actually, I do not know this subject, we have not learned this subject in lectures. But it is an easy way to solve problem.